# How to calculate whether transactions fall into specific periods without loops

Tags: pyspark, crm

I have a Pyspark dataframe of transactions by customer which feeds into a dashboard.  For each rolling 12 month time period, I want to calculate whether a customer is 'New' (never before purchased), 'Retained' (made a purchase in the 12 months before the start of the current time period **and** purchased in the current time period), or 'Reactivated' (made a purchase **prior to** the previous 12 months, didn't purchase in the previous 12 months, and purchased in the current month).

**Clarification of 'current time period':**
If current period is the Rolling 12 Months to the end of September 2022, any purchase from October 2021 to September 2022 falls into the 'current' time period.  Purchases from October 2020 to September 2021 fall into the 'previous 12 months', and purchases from September 2020 and earlier are 'prior to the previous 12 months'.

input:

| customer_id | transaction_id | transaction_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-JAN-10 |
| 1 | 2 | 2019-DEC-15 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-SEP-07 |

intermediate:

| customer_id | txn_id | txn_date | period | txn_current | txn_prev_12m | txn_prior_prev_12m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-JAN-10 | SEP 2022 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2019-DEC-15 | SEP 2022 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-SEP-07 | SEP 2022 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

final:

| customer_id | txn_period | txn_current | txn_prev_12m | txn_prior_prev_12m | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SEP 2022 | 1 | 0 | 2 | Reactivated |

My current solution loops through each required evaluation period (Jan 2022, Feb 2022, Mar 2022, etc.), classifying the customer status for that period.  This step, however, takes hours to process because it has to loop through dozens of different time periods over a dataframe with millions of rows.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but how can I calculate this without looping through each time period and checking whether each individual transaction falls within the bounds of that time period?

Comment: can define or give example of what `purchased in the current time period` means?

Comment: is `current time period` = sept 2021 - sept 2022?

Comment: is `purchase in the 12 months before the start of the current time period` = sept 2020- aug 2021?

Comment: Just edited the original question to give an example of which purchases would fall into which time periods.

Comment: I posted the solution

Comment: did you have a look at my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lag function to extract the previous order by user, Then calculate the datediff of date and previous_date.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

window = W.partitionBy('customer_id').orderBy('transaction_date')

(
    df
    .withColumn('prev_order_date', F.lag('transaction_date').over(window))
    .withColumn('datediff', F.datediff(F.col('transaction_date'), F.col('prev_order_date')))
).show()
```

Comment: This is definitely part of the solution, but the bigger issue is that the Rolling 12 Month time periods mean that the final table needs to have another row showing the same calculation for the period of 'OCT 2022', and another for 'NOV 2022', and so on.  The transaction from September 2022 will be part of these Rolling 12 Month time periods, so each transaction is effectively part of 12 different Rolling 12 Month periods.  I can't seem to figure out a way to generate all of these different evaluations without using a for loop, which makes things incredibly slow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation.
generate a table for all the time periods for the current year
and then cross join that table on all the transactions and perform calculations. the final output is assuming you want the status per customer for each period.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Window
from datetime import *
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


year_start = date(datetime.today().year, 1, 1)
n_months  = 12
date_list = [year_start + relativedelta(months=i) for i in range(n_months)]
dates_formatted = [(d.strftime("%b %Y"),) for d in date_list]
period_df = spark.createDataFrame(dates_formatted, ["period"])

period_df.show()

current_time_period = "SEP 2022"

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("1", "1", "2019-JAN-10"),
        ("1", "2", "2019-DEC-15"),
        ("1", "3", "2022-SEP-07"),
    ],
    ["customer_id", "transaction_id", "transaction_date"],
)

cols = [
    "customer_id",
    "txn_id",
    "txn_date",
    "period",
    "txn_current",
    "txn_prev_12m",
    "txn_prior_prev_12m"
]

txn_period_df = df.crossJoin(period_df)
txn_period_df.show(n=100,truncate=False)

#intermediate:
df = (
    txn_period_df    
    .withColumnRenamed("transaction_id", "txn_id")
    .withColumnRenamed("transaction_date", "txn_date")    
    .withColumn("txn_date_formatted", F.to_date(F.col("txn_date"),"yyyy-MMM-dd"))
    
    # add one month to include tranctions after the 1st
    .withColumn("current_date", F.add_months( F.to_date(F.col("period"),"MMM yyyy") , 1)   )
    
    #any purchase from October 2021 to September 2022 falls into the 'current' time period.
    .withColumn('txn_current_date', F.add_months(F.col("current_date"), -12))    
    .withColumn(
        "txn_current",
        F.when(
            (F.col("txn_date_formatted") >= F.col("txn_current_date"))
            & (F.col("txn_date_formatted") < F.col("current_date")) , F.lit(1)
        ).otherwise(F.lit(0)),
    )
    
    #Purchases from October 2020 to September 2021 fall into the 'previous 12 months'
    .withColumn('txn_prev_12m_date', F.add_months(F.col("txn_current_date"), -12))    
    .withColumn(
        "txn_prev_12m",
        F.when(
            (F.col("txn_date_formatted") >= F.col("txn_prev_12m_date"))
            & (F.col("txn_date_formatted") < F.col("txn_current_date")) , F.lit(1)
        ).otherwise(F.lit(0)),
    )
    
    #and purchases from September 2020 and earlier are 'prior to the previous 12 months'
    .withColumn(
        "txn_prior_prev_12m",
        F.when(
            (F.col("txn_date_formatted") < F.col("txn_prev_12m_date")) , F.lit(1)
        ).otherwise(F.lit(0)),
    )
    .select(cols)    
)

df.show()

cols = [
    "customer_id",
    "txn_period",
    "txn_current",
    "txn_prev_12m",
    "txn_prior_prev_12m",
    "status",
]

txn_agg_window = Window.partitionBy(
    "customer_id",
    "txn_period",
).orderBy(F.col("customer_id"))

#final:
final_df = (
    df
    .withColumnRenamed("period", "txn_period")
    .withColumn(
        "txn_current",
        F.sum("txn_current").over(txn_agg_window),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "txn_prev_12m",
        F.sum("txn_prev_12m").over(txn_agg_window),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "txn_prior_prev_12m",
        F.sum("txn_prior_prev_12m").over(txn_agg_window),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "row_num",
        F.row_number().over(txn_agg_window),
    )
    .filter(F.col("row_num") == 1)
    .drop("row_num")
    
    .withColumn(
        "status",
        F.when(
            (F.col("txn_prior_prev_12m") > 0)
            & (F.col("txn_prev_12m") == 0) 
            & (F.col("txn_current") > 0), F.lit("Reactivated")
        )
        .when(
            (F.col("txn_prev_12m") > 0)
            & (F.col("txn_current") > 0), F.lit("Retained")
        )
        .when(
            (F.col("txn_prior_prev_12m") == 0)
            & (F.col("txn_prev_12m") == 0) 
            & (F.col("txn_current") == 0), F.lit("New")
        )
        .otherwise(F.lit("NA").cast(StringType())),
    )    
    .select(cols)
    .orderBy(F.to_date(F.col("txn_period"),"MMM yyyy").asc())
)

final_df.show()
```

periods:

```
+--------+
|  period|
+--------+
|Jan 2022|
|Feb 2022|
|Mar 2022|
|Apr 2022|
|May 2022|
|Jun 2022|
|Jul 2022|
|Aug 2022|
|Sep 2022|
|Oct 2022|
|Nov 2022|
|Dec 2022|
+--------+
```

intermediate:

```
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+------------------+
|customer_id|txn_id|   txn_date|  period|txn_current|txn_prev_12m|txn_prior_prev_12m|
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+------------------+
|          1|     1|2019-JAN-10|Jan 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     1|2019-JAN-10|Feb 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     1|2019-JAN-10|Mar 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     1|2019-JAN-10|Apr 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     1|2019-JAN-10|May 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     1|2019-JAN-10|Jun 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     1|2019-JAN-10|Jul 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     1|2019-JAN-10|Aug 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     1|2019-JAN-10|Sep 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     1|2019-JAN-10|Oct 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     1|2019-JAN-10|Nov 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     1|2019-JAN-10|Dec 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     2|2019-DEC-15|Jan 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     2|2019-DEC-15|Feb 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     2|2019-DEC-15|Mar 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     2|2019-DEC-15|Apr 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     2|2019-DEC-15|May 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     2|2019-DEC-15|Jun 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     2|2019-DEC-15|Jul 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     2|2019-DEC-15|Aug 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     2|2019-DEC-15|Sep 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     2|2019-DEC-15|Oct 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     2|2019-DEC-15|Nov 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     2|2019-DEC-15|Dec 2022|          0|           0|                 1|
|          1|     3|2022-SEP-07|Jan 2022|          0|           0|                 0|
|          1|     3|2022-SEP-07|Feb 2022|          0|           0|                 0|
|          1|     3|2022-SEP-07|Mar 2022|          0|           0|                 0|
|          1|     3|2022-SEP-07|Apr 2022|          0|           0|                 0|
|          1|     3|2022-SEP-07|May 2022|          0|           0|                 0|
|          1|     3|2022-SEP-07|Jun 2022|          0|           0|                 0|
|          1|     3|2022-SEP-07|Jul 2022|          0|           0|                 0|
|          1|     3|2022-SEP-07|Aug 2022|          0|           0|                 0|
|          1|     3|2022-SEP-07|Sep 2022|          1|           0|                 0|
|          1|     3|2022-SEP-07|Oct 2022|          1|           0|                 0|
|          1|     3|2022-SEP-07|Nov 2022|          1|           0|                 0|
|          1|     3|2022-SEP-07|Dec 2022|          1|           0|                 0|
+-----------+------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+------------------+
```

final:

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------------+-----------+
|customer_id|txn_period|txn_current|txn_prev_12m|txn_prior_prev_12m|     status|
+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------------+-----------+
|          1|  Jan 2022|          0|           0|                 2|         NA|
|          1|  Feb 2022|          0|           0|                 2|         NA|
|          1|  Mar 2022|          0|           0|                 2|         NA|
|          1|  Apr 2022|          0|           0|                 2|         NA|
|          1|  May 2022|          0|           0|                 2|         NA|
|          1|  Jun 2022|          0|           0|                 2|         NA|
|          1|  Jul 2022|          0|           0|                 2|         NA|
|          1|  Aug 2022|          0|           0|                 2|         NA|
|          1|  Sep 2022|          1|           0|                 2|Reactivated|
|          1|  Oct 2022|          1|           0|                 2|Reactivated|
|          1|  Nov 2022|          1|           0|                 2|Reactivated|
|          1|  Dec 2022|          1|           0|                 2|Reactivated|
+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------------+-----------+
```